# How can i create The Live Tile Effect for a ListBoxItem?

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, storyboard, listboxitem

I want to create a `The Live Tile Effect` for my `ListBox`.

I thought about creating a random number between 0 and `ListBox.Items.Count` and then taking that `ListBoxItem` and animating it.

I am using [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/greg_schechter/archive/2007/10/26/enter-the-planerator-dead-simple-3d-in-wpf-with-a-stupid-name.aspx) for animation.

So a basic animation in XAML would look like this:

```
xmlns:pl="clr-namespace:Planerator"

<pl:Planerator x:Name="planerator">
                        <Image Name="logo" Source="somePath">
                            <Image.Triggers>
                                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Image.MouseLeave">
                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="planerator" 
                                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="RotationX"
                                                             From="0" To="360"
                                                             BeginTime="0:0:0"
                                                             Duration="0:0:1"  
                                                             AutoReverse="False"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </EventTrigger>
                            </Image.Triggers>
                        </Image>
                    </pl:Planerator>
```

This is what i have tried so far:

```
<ListBox Name="someList"
         Loaded="someList_Loaded">
</ListBox>
```

`someList_Loaded` Method:

```
    Random random = new Random();
    Planerator planerator = new UI.WPF.Planerator();
    planerator.Name = "planerator";

    someList.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background,
            new Action(
              delegate()
              {
          do
          {
              //planerator.Child = (ListBoxItem)someList.Items[random.Next(0, someList.Items.Count - 1)];

              DoubleAnimation myDoubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation()
               { From = 0, To = 360, Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1)) };

              Storyboard.SetTargetName(planerator, planerator.Name);
              Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(myDoubleAnimation, new PropertyPath("RotationX"));

              Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();
              storyboard.Children.Add(myDoubleAnimation);

              someList.MouseMove += delegate(object newSender, MouseEventArgs args)
              {
                  storyboard.Begin(currentListItem);
              };

              //Sleep 30sec
          }while(true);
      }
  ));
```

Now my problems:

1. First line in the thread's body. That casting is not valid. How would i go about getting a random `ListBoxItem` and assigning it to `planerator.Child`?
2. This line `//Sleep 30sec`: How would i add a wait or sleep here?
3. For creating `The Live Tile Effect`, is this way viable or is there a better way?
4. Will there be any major performance issues?

**EDIT:**

1. `ItemContainerGenerator generator = someList.ItemContainerGenerator;
                                                             ListBoxItem currentListItem = generator.ContainerFromIndex(random.Next(0, someList.Items.Count - 1)) as ListBoxItem;`

**EDIT:**

This is what i got so far, but nothing happens:

```
lstNotifications.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background,
                    new Action(
                        delegate()
                        {
                            ItemContainerGenerator generator = lstNotifications.ItemContainerGenerator;
                            ListBoxItem currentListItem = generator.ContainerFromIndex(random.Next(0, lstNotifications.Items.Count - 1)) as ListBoxItem;

                            var tempObject = Content;
                            Content = null;

                            planerator.Child = currentListItem;

                            Content = tempObject;

                            this.RegisterName(planerator.Name, planerator);

                            DoubleAnimation myDoubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation() { From = 0, To = 360, Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1)) };

                            Storyboard.SetTargetName(planerator, planerator.Name);
                            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(myDoubleAnimation, new PropertyPath(Planerator.RotationXProperty));

                            Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();
                            storyboard.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
                            storyboard.Children.Add(myDoubleAnimation);

                            storyboard.Begin(currentListItem);
                        }
                    ));
```

Any idea why nothing is happening?

Answer (score 1):

Am not sure what you are trying to achieve but here are some things that may or may not help:

1 - As far as I know Planerator.Child is not of type ListBoxItem - so assigning it that type faills - check the type of that property.

2 - Have you tryed using System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30000); ?

3 and 4 I can't answer but maybe Greg Schechter can help:

[Dead Simple 3D in WPF](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/greg_schechter/archive/2007/10/26/enter-the-planerator-dead-simple-3d-in-wpf-with-a-stupid-name.aspx) and [Implementation Details Of The Planerator](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/greg_schechter/archive/2007/11/28/some-implementation-details-of-the-planerator.aspx)